# Getting data from Android app to widget and displaying it

Tags: android, widget

I have started implementing a widget into an application of mine and I am having some trouble getting the data from the application to the widget.

Here is the code for my widget:

```
public class ElectricityMonitorWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static final String WIDGETTAG = "WidgetMood";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        System.out.println("Widget onUpdate called..");

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            System.out.println("In loop. App widget id: "+appWidgetId);
        }
    }    
}
```

In my widget I have only a textview that I want updated with a number from my application. The application gets this number via a web request.

In the `onUpdate()` method which runs periodically I want to be able to update that one textview.

I am not sure how to achieve this.

Do I need to implement a helper class that the widget calls and inside that helper class I have the same method as the application uses to receive the data it uses or?

This is my first time implementing a widget. I have read through the guide on widgets on developer.android.com and that helped me get the widget to show on my phone. The only thing I am missing is the functionality that I describe.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

put this in your widget updating loop

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
  int value = i; //replace with actual value eg from SharedPreferences
  RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.your_widget);
  remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, String.valueOf(value)); //assumed that R.layout.your_widget contains a TextView with R.id_text_view id

  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
  System.out.println("In loop. App widget id: "+appWidgetId);
}
```

Please note, that this code does not specify any action upon user touching the widget (generally you need to specify a PendingIntent and hook it with `RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent` method).

Also, I would suggest that you update your widget when needed and not periodically e.g. your app could send custom Intent to your AppWidgetProvider, which would handle it in overridden `onReceive()` and update RemoteViews on widgets.